# TKINTER frame geometry

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to be able to specify different dimensions for each frame, As I did so with the root frame (App()). I'm not sure how to go about this as I cannot specifically add a new geometry each frame class (Or I don't know how). And also I believe I need to expand my frames as currently when I open the new frame it doesn't match the previous root frames geometry.

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter as ctk

ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("blue")

class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        ctk.CTk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(loginPage)

        self.geometry('450x300')
        self.title('Login Required')
        self.Frame = loginPage(self)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

class loginPage(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ctk.CTkFrame.__init__(self, master)
        ctk.CTkButton(self, text="Open new window",
                      command=lambda: master.switch_frame(pageTwo)).pack()

class pageTwo(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ctk.CTkFrame.__init__(self, master)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

I tried to manually swap the frame geometry with the same method as in the root frame but would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngl I have never seen py-tkinker structured like this yet never-the-less here is and example of code you can use. hope it helps

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter as ctk

ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("blue")

class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        ctk.CTk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(loginPage, None)

        self.geometry('450x300')
        self.title('Login Required')
        self.Frame = loginPage(self)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class, size):
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = frame_class(self)

        if size is not None:
            self._frame.configure(width=size[0], height=size[1])
        self._frame.pack()

class loginPage(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        FrameSize = [500,800] # <--- You can change the [X,Y] Geometry here
        ctk.CTkFrame.__init__(self, master)
        ctk.CTkButton(self, text="Open new window", command = lambda size = FrameSize: master.switch_frame(pageTwo, size)).pack()

class pageTwo(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ctk.CTkFrame.__init__(self, master)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

and if you really wanted it to be like how you define the geometry you can do something like:

```
string_ = '0000x000'
list_ = s.split('x')
```

How I would code it:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import BOLD
# using the '*' wildcard is not the most optimized but the easiest
# it imports everything from tkinter yet most you don't need
import customtkinter as ctk

ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("blue")

class App():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self = master
        self.geometry('450x300+300+300')
        self.title('Login Required')
        
        App.addWindowButton(self, [500,800])
        
    def addWindowButton(self, FrameSize):
        newWindowButton = ctk.CTkButton(self, text="Open new a window")
        newWindowButton.pack(pady=10, ipady=2)
        # you can confiure objects after placing them and pass the object it's self
        # in this example you can destroy the button
        newWindowButton.configure(command = lambda self=self, size = FrameSize, button=newWindowButton: loginPage.switch_frame(self, size, button))

class loginPage:
    '''A class to hold all the LoginPage Functions'''
        
    def switch_frame(self, size, newWindowButton):
        '''Switch to the login frame \n
        You can see this note whenever you hover over the function'''
        
        newWindowButton.destroy()
        
        # creates frame object
        frame_ = ctk.CTkFrame(self, bg_color="#151515")
        frame_.configure(width=size[0], height=size[1])
        #frame_.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True), use this to have the frame fill the window
        frame_.pack(pady=20)
        # you need this so the frame does not resize to conform to a child-object 
        frame_.pack_propagate(False)
        
        # adds the 'Login Window' text
        ctk.CTkLabel(frame_, text="Login Window", font=('Candara', 23, BOLD)).pack(pady=(30,0))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = ctk.CTk()
    App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm really just trying to figure out tkinter as a whole and someone suggested I use classes, Should I not use classes? Or are my classes just coded and structured poorly? lol

Comment: No worries! You can use classes and I don't think your classes are poorly structured as much as they are limiting. I will edit my post to add how I would structure the code and add some things you can play around with. It is not the most optimized yet it's easy to understand.